# Как добавить в масив только уникальные обьекты ?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть масив с обьектами:

```
 let arr = [
     { name: 'Jahn',
       email: 'john@test.com'
     },
     { name: 'Bob',
       email: 'bob@test.com'
     }
]
```

Мне нужно добавлять обьекты. Как мне добавлять только уникальные обьекты. Например как из такого масива добавить только уникальные обьекты ?

```
let arr2 = [
         { name: 'Max',
           email: 'max@test.com'
         },
         { name: 'Bob',
           email: 'bob@test.com'
         },
         { name: 'Jahn',
           email: 'john@test.com'
         },
         { name: 'Julie',
           email: 'julie@test.com'
         }
    ]
```

Должен получиться такой масив в результате:

```
let result = [
          { name: 'Jahn',
            email: 'john@test.com'
          },
          { name: 'Bob',
            email: 'bob@test.com'
          },
          { name: 'Max',
           email: 'max@test.com'
          },
          { name: 'Julie',
            email: 'julie@test.com'
          }
     ]
```

Уникальное свойство у обьекта это `email`

Comment: а почему бы не использовать email в качестве ключа например `let users = {'example@gmail.com': {....}};` ? или в контексте вашей задачи токое решение не подходит?

Comment: у меня уже есть готовый масив и к нему нужно добавить юзеров которые приходят с api

Answer (score 2):

Ну как-то так, получился довольно длинный пример, все можно было и записать одной функцией, но я разделил на целых 3. Моей целью было показать  алгоритм а красиво оформить думаю сами сможете.

```js
let arr1 = [
    { 
        name: 'Jahn',
        email: 'john@test.com'
    },
    {  name: 'Bob',
        email: 'bob@test.com'
    }
];

let arr2 = [
    {
        name: 'Max',
        email: 'max@test.com'
    },
    {
        name: 'Bob',
        email: 'bob@test.com'
     },
     { 
        name: 'Jahn',
        email: 'john@test.com'
     },
     { 
        name: 'Julie',
        email: 'julie@test.com'
     }
];

function array2object(array, field){
    let res = {};
    
    for(let i in array)
        if (!(i in res))
            res[array[i][field]] = array[i];
    
    return res;
}

function object2array(object)
{
    let res = [];
    
    for(let i in object)
        res.push(object[i]);
    
    return res;
}

function union(arr1, arr2)
{    
    for (let i in arr2)
        if (!(i in arr1))  
            arr1[i] = arr2[i];
        
    return arr1;
}

// первый параметр это сам массив а второй уникальное поле 
// которое будет ключом
let obj1 = array2object(arr1, 'email');
let obj2 = array2object(arr2, 'email');

let result = object2array(union(obj1, obj2));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще один вариант.

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'Jahn',
    email: 'john@test.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    email: 'bob@test.com'
  }
]

const arr2 = [{
    name: 'Max',
    email: 'max@test.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    email: 'bob@test.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jahn',
    email: 'john@test.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'Julie',
    email: 'julie@test.com'
  }
]

function addUnique(arrTarget, arrSource, field) {
  const res = arrTarget.splice();
  arrSource.forEach(f => {
    if (!res.some(s => s[field] === f[field]))
      res.push(f);
  });
  return res;
}
const res = addUnique(arr, arr2, 'email');
console.log(res);
```